# ブラウザにHTMLのソースコードがそのまま表示されてしまう

Tags: html, http

ESPlorerを使ってESP8266のWebServerを作っています。
下はそのUIコードですが、コードがそのものがブラウザ(safari,googlechrome)に表示されてしまいます。
このコードかブラウザに問題があるのでしょうか。

```
wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
wifi.sta.config("106F3F76046E","p518fm1rhp3na")
print("Connected on " .. wifi.sta.getip()) 
wifi.sta.connect() 
--tmr.alarm(0, 1000, 1, checkWifiStatus) 
gpio.mode(7, gpio.OUTPUT) 
gpio.write(7, gpio.LOW) 
if srv~=nil then
  srv:close()
end

srv=net.createServer(net.TCP, 3) 
print("Server created on " .. wifi.sta.getip()) 
srv:listen(80,function(conn) conn:on("receive",function(conn,request) 
print(request) 
_, j = string.find(request, 'led_light_switch=') 
if j ~= nil then command = string.sub(request, j + 1) 
if command == 'on' then gpio.write(7, gpio.HIGH) 
else gpio.write(7, gpio.LOW) 
end 
end 

conn:send("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n Hello, ESP8266.")
conn:send('<!DOCTYPE html>') 
conn:send('<html lang="en">') 
conn:send('<head><meta charset="utf- 8" />') 
conn:send('<title>Hello, World!</title></head>') 
conn:send('<body><h1>Hello, World!</h1>')

if gpio.read(7) == gpio.HIGH then led = "ON" 
else led = "OFF" 
end 
conn:send('<p>The light is ' .. led .. '</p>') 
conn:send('<form method="post">') 
conn:send('<input type="radio" name="led_light_switch" value="on">ON</input><br />') 
conn:send('<input type="radio" name="led_light_switch" value="off">OFF</input><br />') 
conn:send('<input type="submit" value="Light Switch" />') 
conn:send('</form></body></html>') 
end)
end)
```

Comment: soramimi 回答ありがとうございました。どうやらそれが原因だったようです。

Answer (score 3):

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n`を送出している直後に、`Content-Type: text/html\r\n`を追加してみるとどうでしょうか？